# SWIG 3 wrap untemplated class with templated constructor

Tags: python, c++, templates, constructor, swig

We have an untemplated C++ class with a templated constructor. We were able to use SWIG 2 to make a Python wrapper, but the same code fails in SWIG 3: the wrapper class's constructor raises AttributeError("No constructor defined"). I'm hoping someone can suggest a clean fix or workaround.

Here an extract of the C++ header:

```
class FootprintSet {
public:
    template <typename ImagePixelT>
    FootprintSet(image::Image<ImagePixelT> const& img,
                 Threshold const& threshold,
                 int const npixMin=1, bool const setPeaks=true);

    FootprintSet(geom::Box2I region);
...
```

and the main part of the SWIG interface file:

```
%shared_ptr(lsst::afw::detection::FootprintSet);

%include "lsst/afw/detection/FootprintSet.h"

%define %footprintSetOperations(PIXEL)
%template(FootprintSet) FootprintSet<PIXEL>;
%enddef

%extend lsst::afw::detection::FootprintSet {
%footprintSetOperations(boost::uint16_t)
%footprintSetOperations(int)
%footprintSetOperations(float)
%footprintSetOperations(double)
}
```

One crude workaround I've considered is to replace the templated constructor in the header with explicit versions for each specialization, e.g.:

```
class FootprintSet {
public:
#ifndef SWIG
    template <typename ImagePixelT>
    FootprintSet(image::Image<ImagePixelT> const& img,
                 Threshold const& threshold,
                 int const npixMin=1, bool const setPeaks=true);
#else
    FootprintSet(image::Image<boost::unit16> const& img,
                 Threshold const& threshold,
                 int const npixMin=1, bool const setPeaks=true);
    FootprintSet(image::Image<int> const& img,
                 Threshold const& threshold,
                 int const npixMin=1, bool const setPeaks=true);
    FootprintSet(image::Image<float> const& img,
                 Threshold const& threshold,
                 int const npixMin=1, bool const setPeaks=true);
    FootprintSet(image::Image<double> const& img,
                 Threshold const& threshold,
                 int const npixMin=1, bool const setPeaks=true);
#endif

    FootprintSet(geom::Box2I region);
...
```

Or (probably better) put something similar in the SWIG interface, instead of the C++ header.

Still, I'm hoping there is a simpler solution. We would like to update to SWIG 3 for the C++11 support, but this is a significant blocker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear to be a regression in SWIG.  Here's a reduced example:

```
price@price-laptop:~/test $ cat test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace test {

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T bar);
    ~Foo() {}
    void working() const {
        std::cout << "WORKING" << std::endl;
    }
};

}

#endif
price@price-laptop:~/test $ cat test.cc 
#include "test.h"

namespace test {

template <typename T>
Foo::Foo(T) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template Foo::Foo(int);

}

price@price-laptop:~/test $ cat test.i
%feature("autodoc", "1");
%module(package="test", docstring="test") testLib

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"

%extend test::Foo {
     %template(Foo) Foo<int>;
}

price@price-laptop:~/test $ clang++ -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o libtest.dylib test.cc
```

With SWIG 2.0.12:

```
price@price-laptop:~/test $ swig -python -c++ test.i
price@price-laptop:~/test $ clang++ -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o _testLib.so test_wrap.cxx -L. -ltest -I/usr/include/python2.7
price@price-laptop:~/test $ python -c "import testLib; testLib.Foo(1)"
i
```

With SWIG 3.0.2, it seems to treat `Foo::Foo` as an ordinary function, warns about it not having a return type, and ignores it:

```
price@price-laptop:~/test $ swig -python -c++ test.i
test.i:11: Warning 504: Function test::Foo::Foo(int) must have a return type. Ignored.
price@price-laptop:~/test $ clang++ -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o _testLib.so test_wrap.cxx -L. -ltest -I/usr/include/python2.7
price@price-laptop:~/test $ python -c "import testLib; testLib.Foo(1)"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "testLib.py", line 82, in __init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): raise AttributeError("No constructor defined")
AttributeError: No constructor defined
```

Suggest you kick this upstream.

---

EDIT: This has been [fixed upstream](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/245).

Comment: Thank you. I reported it as a SWIG issue <github.com/swig/swig/issues/245>; using your self-contained example.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler might need some help figuring out that `Image` is a templated type. Try putting `typename`:

```
FootprintSet(typename image::Image<ImagePixelT> const& img, ...
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I tried it, but unfortunately it did not help.